# Avoid kaspersky alert "Connection not Protected" in selenium Java

Tags: selenium

How to avoid kaspersky alert "Connection not Protected" in selenium Java.
I do not even know is it alert. But usual options set for alert do not help e.g.

`options.setAcceptInsecureCerts(true);`

And I do not want to change antivirus or to make my PC insecure by changing the computer settings.
[image]

Comment: You'll need to add that cert to the whitelist... maybe check here: https://support.kaspersky.com/KESWin/11/en-us/131348.htm

Comment: What about just locate the element with text "I understand ..." and click on it?

Comment: After click on link I understand it will display kasperski message box, and Not sure that is chrome option that webdriver supports.